# Given string want to filter out certain part of string into an arraylist

Tags: java, string, filter

I have string:

```
String s = #Jay125,150012 90,#Jay222,150043 00,
```

- I want to filter out value after jay(125,222) and add that to separate `ArrayList`.
- I want to filter out 150012, 151243 together add that to separate `ArrayList`.
- I want to filter out 90,00 together add that to separate `ArrayList`.

I tried by doing this but it doesn't quite do what I want

```
Pattern reg = Pattern.compile(",");
ArrayList<String> jay = reg.splitAsStream(s))    
                           .filter(role -> role.contains("Jay"))
                           .map(String::trim)
                           .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
```

Comment: Can you clarify the input format a bit? Is it always "#Jay<some numbers>,<some numbers> <some numbers>,"?

Comment: O i get jay125 and jay222 but I only want that part to get me 125 and 222,  for the second part I want both the numbers to be seperated to be added in two diff arraylists

Comment: Yes Eskapone that is always the format repeated

Comment: The fixed code is up there I just confusion on how to do it exactly they way I need

Comment: O ya thanks wait so for splitting the numbers I have right now how would i split that because right now I filter out string using if it contains 15, I want both of them to be seperated into two diff arraylist problem we won't know the exact amount digit. It always start with 15 and have space in between second value

Comment: I know I can probably use str.split by " " tat would make it array string so tat would not work right?

Comment: Is there maybe way to use regex to replaceall before space and after space?

Comment: that works for me but just one thing when it maps it out the first string is automatically has space before it for some reason is there way that can be stopped

Comment: might be sth would my ide cause only the first one is acting like that but everything else works

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood correctly your case, you're having a `String` whose pattern is in the form `#Jay<Number>,<Number> <Number>` and then it keeps repeating itself. Also, you would like to have every bit of this pattern (jay bit, first number bit and second number bit) stored in three separate lists.

As suggested in the comments, you could achieve this with a regex using capturing groups to identify the three portions and retrieve them at every match.

`#(Jay\d+),(\d+) (\d+)`

Here is a link to test the regex:

https://regex101.com/r/ULtDTu/1

Here is a code snippet with the implementation:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "#Jay125,150012 90,#Jay222,150043 00,";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("#(Jay\\d+),(\\d+) (\\d+)");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);

        List<String> listJay = new ArrayList<>();
        List<String> listFirstSubNum = new ArrayList<>();
        List<String> listSecSubNum = new ArrayList<>();

        while (matcher.find()) {
            listJay.add(matcher.group(1));
            listFirstSubNum.add(matcher.group(2));
            listSecSubNum.add(matcher.group(3));
        }

        System.out.println(listJay);
        System.out.println(listFirstSubNum);
        System.out.println(listSecSubNum);
    }
}
```

You can also test the code here:

https://ideone.com/0hwpyl